# org-mode has no syntax highlighting unless I start with evil

Tags: org-mode, evil, microsoft-windows

When I start emacs with evil-mode in my rc (`(evil-mode 1)`) I get syntax highlighting for .org files. However, when I do not, I do not get any syntax highlighting, even when trying `M-x font-lock-mode` a couple times. This occurs even when I delete `.emacs` and `.emacs.d`. How do I fix this?

Comment: FWIW, I do `emacs -Q foo.org` and the buffer is fontified (on Linux - I don't do Windows). Can you try that? If it doesn't work, add the version of emacs you are using: `C-u M-x emacs-version`.

Comment: @NickD When I run `emacs.exe` with `-Q` the file does not have syntax highlighting. My version is GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2021-03-2.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help: you'll have to wait for somebody who does Windows. 27.2 on Linux fontifies Org mode files.